# read and write images in structure folder

Tags: android, image, file-io

I'm building a travel infomation. My app has about 500 images in structure folder. [image]
I don't know how to read/write by my application.
I usually read and write image by id through drawable. But put 500 image on drawable folder may be a wrong place.
what should I do? It would be awesome if someone had some example code.

Comment: Out them in your asset folder.  Then, when you need them, read it into a Bitmap via BitmapFactory.createBitmap and put it into your ImageView via setImageBitmap.  Or draw it directly via canvas, whichever you need.

Comment: @GabeSechan tks for fast reply, I'll try